# Map reducing a collection of coordinate pairs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapreduce

I've been a developer for a couple years now, and one concept I don't seem to quite get is map reduce.

I have a collection of coordinates that define squares, with each value being an array of two arrays.  Each internal array is itself an array of two numeric values.

```
//Example values:
//Each value is the following [[left, top],[right, bottom]]
var boundingBoxes = [
[[20, 20], [50, 30]],
[[15, 25], [35, 45]],
[[25, 25], [40, 40]]
]
```

I need to reduce this collection to a set of coordinates that will allow me to define a rectangle that surrounds all of rectangles whose coordinates are in the collection.  So the lowest value for each left and top, and the highest values for right and bottom.

```
//Output for above values should be
[[15, 20], [50, 45]]
```

Further background.  The structure of the coordinates is coming from d3.path().bounds(d).  I'm getting the bounds for multiple states and creating a bounding box that encapsulates all of them; for use in zooming on redefined collections of states on a map.

Comment: Not sure what your question is -- are you asking how to do this with D3 (hint: use `d3.max` and `d3.min`) or how to do it with map-reduce?

Comment: How to do it with map-reduce.

Comment: And what particular map-reduce implementation are you using?

Comment: Just plain JavaScript.  Underscore is also an option.  As is D3 if it has anything like that.

Comment: Well in D3 it's just `xmin = d3.min(boundingBoxes, function(d) { return d[0][0]; }); xmax = d3.max(boundingBoxes, function(d) { return d[1][0]; });` and similarly for y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this with `reduce` the following would do the job:

```
var boundingBoxes = [
  [[20, 20], [50, 30]],
  [[15, 25], [35, 45]],
  [[25, 25], [40, 40]]
];

var result = boundingBoxes.reduce(function(prev,curr){
  var left = Math.min(prev[0][0], curr[0][0]),
      top = Math.min(prev[0][1], curr[0][1]),
      right = Math.max(prev[1][0], curr[1][0]),
      bottom = Math.max(prev[1][1], curr[1][1]);

  return [[left,top],[right,bottom]];
});
```

The callback function of `reduce` takes the `previous` and the `current` element from the array. You could set an initial value for the first "previous" as second param of `reduce`. If you leave out the initial value, reduce starts with the first and second element.

You just have to compare each value an return the element with the appropriate values from the callback.